# Is dealloc always called? Even when you swipe close an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, dealloc

I wonder if dealloc is always called when you close a ViewController in Objective-C for iOS. I've done some tests and it seems like it. Except I don't get any logs when I swipe close the application. I figured that maybe XCode doesn't log things if you fully close the app like that.

The reason I wonder this is because I'm sending analytic data when one of the ViewControllers closes and I kinda need to know if dealloc is always called or if there's any better way doing this.

Comment: No it not always called, If you not properly manage controller object than even if it removes from navigation stack dealloc will not called, because it is still live in memory. Haven't test for swipe to close app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not defined when `dealloc` will be called for a view controller (or pretty much any class), therefore don't use it for sending analytics.

Use `viewDidDisappear` instead, which you can rely on to be called when the view controller has been removed.

Comment: Its not fair to say "Don't use it", what you mean is that you shouldn't use it in the case of analytics (I know you go on to elaborate this but just to be safe...)

Comment: @DanielGalasko Agreed; my answer was referring to the OPs use of `dealloc`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! But won't it be called if you add a child viewController on top of the current one?

Comment: @KristofferKitoJansson Yes it will; you might need to keep more state about when the view controller is being removed and it was the top view.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get notified when app is killed via Swiping , you can use `applicationWillTerminate` method and in this method , you can check for current view controller in navigation stack and send analytical data for that View controller .

Comment: I did not know about that method! That's great! I can check if there's unsent data there and make sure everything is sent before it terminates. Thanks!